# Entity Framework Table per Hierarchy not creating Discriminator

Tags: c#, entity-framework, table-per-hierarchy

I created an inheritance hierarchy after a few migrations. Now when I update the database using code first migrations, code-first is not automatically creating the discriminator field. I have since dropped the table and recreated it (using code-first migrations) without any luck. The only thing I can think of is that there are no additional "non-virtual" properties in the derived classes--the inheritance structure was created to enforce a business rule that only a certain derived type can have a relationship with another entity.

Base Type:

```
public abstract class Process
{

    private ICollection<ProcessSpecification> _specifications { get; set; }

    protected Process()
    {
        _specifications = new List<ProcessSpecification>();
    }        

    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public Int32 ToolId { get; set; }

    public virtual Tool Tool { get; set; }        
    public virtual ICollection<ProcessSpecification> Specifications
    {
        get { return _specifications; }
        set { _specifications = value; }
    }

}
```

Derived class (no different/unique scalar properties):

```
public class AssemblyProcess : Process
{
    private ICollection<AssemblyProcessComponent> _components;

    public AssemblyProcess()
    {
        _components = new List<AssemblyProcessComponent>();            
    }

    public virtual ICollection<AssemblyProcessComponent> Components
    {
        get { return _components; }
        set { _components = value; }
    }
}
```

Another derived type

```
public class MachiningProcess : Process
{
    private ICollection<MachiningProcessFeature> _features;

    public MachiningProcess()
    {
        _features = new List<MachiningProcessFeature>();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<MachiningProcessFeature> Features { get { return _features; } set { _features = value; } }
}
```

Is code-first not adding the discriminator column in the database because it doesn't see any differences between the derived classes (because of there not being any unique "non-virtual" properties)? If so, how do I get around this? If not, what are some reasons why code-first would not automatically create the discriminator column in the database? I have another TPH structure that works exactly the way it's supposed to.

**DbContext:**

```
public LineProcessPlanningContext()
        : base("LineProcessPlanning")
    {
    }   

public DbSet<Component> Components { get; set; }
public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
public DbSet<Feature> Features { get; set; }
public DbSet<OperationDefinition> OperationDefinitions { get; set; }
public DbSet<PartDesign> PartDesigns { get; set; }
public DbSet<Process> Processes { get; set; }
public DbSet<ProcessPlan> ProcessPlans { get; set; }
public DbSet<ProcessPlanStep> ProcessPlanSteps { get; set; }
public DbSet<ProductionLine> ProductionLines { get; set; }       
public DbSet<StationCycleDefinition> StationCycleDefinitions { get; set; }
public DbSet<StationCycleStep> StationCycleSteps { get; set; }
public DbSet<StationDefinition> StationDefinitions { get; set; }
public DbSet<UnitOfMeasurement> UnitsOfMeasurement { get; set; }        
public DbSet<Tool> Tools { get; set; }
```

I also tried creating "dummy" properties that are unique to each derived type. Code migrations added the new properties as columns to the table, but the migration did not create a discriminator column.

Comment: I have done exactly what you have above and my tables get created appropriately with the Discriminator column.  Can you show me the usage of your context and how you have setup your context?

Comment: I provided the DbContext. "Feature" is an abstract base class for another entity hierarchy; code migrations created a discriminator column for that entity in the database--without having to create a dbset for each derived class.

Comment: Hmm, looks like you have some code in the two tables in question (MachiningProcessFeature and ProcessSpecification) which might have an impact on your problem.  Can you share *all* your code or cut it down to a version which we can reproduce the issue or at least have a more closely matching example?

Comment: Was the cause of this ever determined?  I'm having the same issue.

Comment: I think it had something to do with automatic code migrations not recognizing the structure change (it previously had not been an inheritance structure). When I deleted the tables and started fresh (and also added some fluent configurations) everything worked the way that it was supposed to. I should have been able to solve the problem without having to delete the database.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out the cause of this in my situation, same as yours.   The base class is `abstract`, therefore EF won't create a TPH table for that class since it can't be instantiated.  As a result of the abstract base class, EF will create tables for each of the derived classes, and therefore no need for a discriminator column.

In my case, it was acceptable to remove `abstract` from the base class.  Once I did this, EF's TPH worked as expected.

Comment: I had another inheritance structure that was also abstract; that structure did not experience any problems.

Comment: I think that you only have one class bellow the abstract class where the discriminator is not created any more classes where it is.

Comment: @CoroveiAndrei What you mean is that `Discriminator` table is not created when we have only single concrete class that inherits from the abstract base class?

Comment: exactly. The discriminator is not created when there is only one concrete class.