# Avoid using discriminator in EF Core when dealing with inheritance

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-database-first

Problems started after switching from EF to EF Core (3.1).

I have a base abstract class and a derived class which is created dynamicaly in runtime (using reflection).

entity configuration of my base type was (**EF**):

```
        ToTable("TableName", "dbo");
        HasKey(t => t.Id);

        HasRequired(t => t.prop1).WithMany().HasForeignKey(t => t.prop1);
        Property(t => t.prop2).IsRequired();
        Property(t => t.prop3).IsRequired();
```

I built base class  with this configuration and dynamic class with modelBuilder.Entity(type).
And everything worked fine. I could get instances of my base class using `context.Objects` and instances of the dynamic class using `Activator.CreateInstance(type)`.

Now I have same configuration but for **EF Core**:

```
        builder.ToTable("TableName", "dbo");
        builder.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        builder.HasOne(t => t.prop1).WithMany().HasForeignKey(t => t.prop1);
        builder.Property(t => t.prop2).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(t => t.prop3).IsRequired();
```

But in EF Core getting objects from context gives an error "Invalid column name 'Discriminator'". Yes, I don't have discriminator column in my table (apparently it's required when TPH pattern is used) but it worked perfectly without it in EF. How did **EF** dealt with inheritance in that case? Moreover, creating such column and populating it with the same data (derived class name) seems to be useless. It feels like there should be something I'm missing.

So, my question is:
Is there any way to fix the problem without creating a discriminator column?

Comment: Please post the schema from the database, sounds like the EF version didn't use the default _string_ typed `Discriminator` column.

Comment: P.S. i use DataBase first approach

Comment: Why on the earth you do that? What's the purpose of a dynamic class if it is using only the properties/columns of the base class/table? Is it some sort of a proxy? Or? Can you provide more details about the use case in order to see what can be done.

Comment: dynamic class has not only base columns (yes, it's proxy). it reading column names from configuration file

Comment: my table has required properties (it defined in base class) and additional (configuring with configuration file), so i need to create a dynamic class with base and additional properties

Answer (score 0):

A default EF TPH will generally go across to EF Core without too many issues, however the customisation options are different between the two, for instance in *core* we can now easily manipulate the discriminator via fluent notation:  https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/hasdiscriminator-method

Check that your base class is *NOT* abstract: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34646164/1690217

- If your base class *IS* `abstract` then you will have to manually configure the `Discriminator` column: https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/inheritance/table-per-hierarchy#configuration

Also check that your database schema from the previous EF migrations actually has the `Discriminator` column and that it is a string type, the actual values *should* be the name of the types, however it is possible that you have configured or applied conventions elsewhere that override the default behaviour (in either the EF or the EF Core implementations)

*If you include the actual schema in the database or the migration entries that build the tables you might get a more definitive answer.*

Comment: Yes, I don't have a dicriminator column (wrote it in the end of question). And i don't want to create it, beacuse i have only one derived class and my base class is abstract. I do not see the point of creating a column filled with same values

Comment: If there is only one table, then you should use TPT for this type, not TPH

Comment: Make sure that there is no `DbSet<baseType>`  in your context, or any fluent configuration for the base type.

Comment: sorry for misinterpreting your issue, I thought you _wanted_ the discriminator to just work silently like it did in EF

Comment: You could also try https://stackoverflow.com/a/62597286/1690217 not sure it working in core though

Comment: I can't ignore base type because I need to use it too in some cases. Maybe,  creating 2 different DbContextes (1 for only base type, second for only derived) could help? But I'm afraid that in the second DbContext if I don't configure properties of the base class i will lose them in my derived class or somehow break the relationship between  them

Comment: If there are multiple types in the `DbContext` then you MUST have a discriminator column, that is how it works. You can get around the base implementation in other ways like using interfaces or extension methods, but a Row is **NOT** polymorphic, from EFs point of view it can only be one concrete type, if the context _thinks_ there are multiple types on the table discriminator (or another column of your choosing) tells it which row to deserialize as.